# Why should I use destructive style

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I read that Destructive style in UIAlertController should be used when action might change or delete data. This seems like a fairly simple to understand. But when I can set a label of a button and allow to define action of the button, what's the point of using distructive style? So, I assume it's gotta be something in the background that works differently than other styels. But how?

Comment: I am sorry, but this is the definition of "Unclear what you are asking". Destructive is a visual cue to let users know this may cause data loss. What is so difficult to figure out?

Comment: I don't know why it is unclear. I just wanted to know why should I use "destructive" style over other styles when I can define my own actions and attached to the alertview. Edit : The same thing can be done with setting your own message and custom label of a button. I was thinking if there is any clean up job done in the background when I use this style over others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructive actions are a way to alert the user that the action may lead to data loss. It is meant as a visual cue by setting the text to red.

Here is how Mail uses it to differentiate between archiving messages and deleting them:

[image]

Ideally, you'd want to use the destructive action for actions which cannot be reversed and may cause data loss to the user.